# Two fixed elements z-index issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

Hello I ve got the following example https://pensive-heyrovsky-54b9e2.netlify.app/ where I got the text that is in fixed postion, and i want to go under the fixed position photo, my issues is that the text will go over the photo.

I tried switching between different z-index values but no luck because if i increase the z-index of the photo will be on the whole screen. Its mandatory that photo and text to stay fixed to obtain the animation needed.

The effect that i try to obtain : https://ecstatic-ritchie-78a695.netlify.app/ (but not with  background-attachement fixed because is not compatible with ios)

```js
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

// var scene1 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({


var scene1 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: '.trigger-2 ',
    duration: 0,
    triggerHook: 1,
  })
  .setClassToggle('.pos-fixed-to-relative', 'stayy')
  .addTo(controller)
```

```css
.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("./basm.png");
  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 500px;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.paralaax {
  background-image: url("./bundle 3.png");
  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 500px;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container-3 {
  height: 400px;
}

.container-100vh {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 767px;
}

.bck-black {
  background: black;
}

.z-index {
  z-index: 2
}

.overflow {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.photo-full {
  min-height: 767px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.background-image {
  /* background-image:url('./test-background.webp');   */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.photo-full.stay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.middle-page {
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  font-size: 90px;
}

.bck-2.stayy {
  background-attachment: initial;
}

.middle-page {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.trigger-2 {
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
  background: salmon;
}

.background-white {
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.container-50vh {
  height: 60vh;
}

.photo-full.stayy {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="position-absolute"></div>
<div class="position-realative background-image bck-2 position-relative">
  <div class="sections-normal container-100vh background-white ">
    <div class="w-100 photo-full">
      <div class="middle-page">Hello, I am a fixed text, I want to go under next image</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-phoen  container-100vh ">

    <img class="photo-full  pos-fixed-to-relative" src="./test-background.webp" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-100vh position-realative trigger-2 ">

</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.7/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: trigger-2 {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    background: salmon;
}

Comment: I think you did not understand, i edited the post with an example

Comment: okay let me check again